# Failed to start MySQL Community Server

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

Following error is being showed while checking the status for my-sql .

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.3

Mysql: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.27, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

```
mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2019-08-31 08:27:11 CEST; 1min 12s ago
  Process: 18000 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Aug 31 08:27:11 myserver systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Aug 31 08:27:11 myserver systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 31 08:27:11 myserver systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
Aug 31 08:27:11 myserver systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Aug 31 08:27:11 myserver systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Aug 31 08:27:11 myserver systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Aug 31 08:27:11 myserver systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Aug 31 08:27:11 myserver systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 31 08:27:11 myserver systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

I tried to start using mysqld command which ended with following error

```
mysqld: Error on realpath() on '/var/lib/mysql-files' (Error 2 - No such file or directory)
2019-08-31T12:51:57.596969Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2019-08-31T12:51:57.597359Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to access directory for --secure-file-priv. Please make sure that directory exists and is accessible by MySQL Server. Supplied value : /var/lib/mysql-files
2019-08-31T12:51:57.597485Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2019-08-31T12:51:57.597607Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
```

my.cnf

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram
```

Comment: This only really tells us that systemd tried several times to start mysqld, but it failed every time, so systemd gave up. To find the actual error, check the mysql logs (in `/var/log/mysql/`, most likely `error.log` in that directory) or try running `sudo mysqld` directly instead of using `systemctl` (in which case the errors will be printed in your terminal window).

Comment: error.log file doesnt have anything logged , i tried msqld and ended up with an error , i have updated the question.

Comment: Check permissions.  Be 'root' when you install.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The errors you got on the console when running `mysqld` directly include:

> 2019-08-31T12:51:57.597359Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to access directory for --secure-file-priv. Please make sure that directory exists and is accessible by MySQL Server. Supplied value : /var/lib/mysql-files

That's your problem.

To resolve it, first check the user that your `mysqld` is attempting to run as; this will be the user "mysql" in a default Debian install (I assume it should be the same for Ubuntu); to verify this, check `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and look for a "user = xxx" line.

Once you know what user `mysqld` is trying to run as, check that the directory `/var/lib/mysql-files` exists (`sudo mkdir /var/lib/mysql-files` if it doesn't) and is owned by the user `mysqld` runs as (`sudo chown mysql /var/lib/mysql-files` if it isn't; replace "mysql" in the `chown` command with the correct user name if you're configured to run as a different user).

Then try `sudo mysqld` again and you should either get a successful `mysqld` startup, or (if there are other problems with your setup) a new and different error message.

Comment: i have update the question with my.cnf contents , there is no user=xxx , i am running as ```mysqld```  as root –

Comment: instead of sudo mysqld, you can run sudo service mysql start

Comment: @zawhtut - Using `service mysqld start` (or, depending on distro, `systemctl start mysqld`) causes errors to be written to the logs. Running `mysqld` directly will show any errors on your terminal, which is generally more convenient for debugging, as was the case in this question.

Answer (score 2):

For me, I ran some cache clearing operations to free up space using tools like Stacer, and then MySQL started showing problems.

Use this to get some clues first

```
grep mysql /var/log/syslog | grep ERROR
```

If the error says, **Could not open file '/var/log/mysql/error.log' for error logging: No such file or directory**
then clearly, the log files were cleaned up.

Use this to first create the MySQL directory and grant all permissions for MySQL to use that folder.

```
> sudo mkdir /var/log/mysql
> sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/log/mysql
> sudo service mysql restart
```

This solution has nothing to do with the my.cnf files and is completely safe on data.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the error in question?

Comment: Thank you for sharing, I had accidently deleted the /var/log  folder and then mysql started throwing this error, resolved after created folder.

Answer (score 0):

Check for below.

1. Check if file is exists.
2. Check file permissions.
3. If Selinux is enabled fix it with below.

   $ semanage fcontext -a -e /var/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql-files

   $ restorecon -R /var/lib/mysql-files

   Make sure /var/lib/mysql is empty, Then Try to start server:

   $ service mysqld start

Check this link also it may help https://askubuntu.com/questions/835541/mysql-install-db-on-ubuntu-16-04